# topic_tools, relay

Tags: ros, topic-tools

[image: Rosanswers logo]

about topic_tools, relay, will this tool cost more resources than remap？ I mean will it copy 1 more data from in_topic to out_topic?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276659/topic_tools,-relay/) by [asimay_y](https://answers.ros.org/users/20955/asimay_y/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2017-11-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes; the topic_tools relay node uses more resources than remapping, because it is a separate process that subscribes to the topic, copies the message and publishes it on a new topic.

The resource and performance impact will depend on your data and the computer(s) you're running ROS on. For most systems the resource use is very low, but if you have large messages (tens of megabytes or larger), topics that are published frequently (100Hz or more) or a low latency deadline (5ms or less) then you should measure the performance impact on your system.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [asimay_y](https://answers.ros.org/users/20955/asimay_y/) on 2017-11-25**:
Thank you very much. Dear.
and another question I also want to know: so the "remap" can also be used across files and nodes, right?  means I defined remap topic at where I want.

**Comment by [harderthan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34798/harderthan/) on 2020-02-26**:
Cool. Thanks